# Retrieve WCF Rest Response in Client

Tags: wcf, rest

I'm using the WebChannelFactory<> to create a channel and interact with a WCF REST Service.

When there is an error, I want to retrieve the response from the channel to read the error message from the body of the response. But I cannot figure out how to get the response stream.

Here is my code:

```
using (var cf = new WebChannelFactory<T>(new Uri(url)))
{
    var channel = cf.CreateChannel();

    using (new OperationContextScope(channel as IContextChannel))
    {
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingRequest.Headers
        .Add("x-st-authtoken", HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Constants.General_AuthorizedToken));

        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingRequest.Headers
        .Add("x-st-tesskey", HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Constants.General_SessionKey));
        try
        {
            a(channel);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Status: " + ((int)WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingResponse.StatusCode).ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

In the catch statement, I want to include the data from the Response body...

It seems like an obvious thing, but I can't seem to find any information on the internet or anything.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it will throw a [WebException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.aspx).

so if you explicitly catch that type you can get use the WebException.Response property (which is an HttpWebReponse) on the exception and you can get the content from its stream.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason for you to use ChannelFactory to interact with the REST service. I think it is easier to use HttpWebRequest object to invoke the REST service and there you can get the respone stream when an error is throw on the server.

Also check out RestSharp API through which you can achieve your task to read the response stream.